# Why should the eigenvalues of random matrices reflect zeta function zeroes?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemann-zeta, random-matrices

> Why should the eigenvalues of random matrices reflect zeta function zeroes?

[This article](http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2013/02/math-and-nature-universality/) is related to the question.

Is this a particular property of $2$-dimensional objects? Could random vectors also model the "universality phenomena" -- globally random distribution of zeroes combined with local repulsion of zeroes?

Is this because matrices eigenvectors are orthogonal to each other, the orthogonality modeling the repulsion / mutual exclusion of the energy states of real systems? Are there any instances where CP decompositions of "random tensors" model physical systems ? Why matrices ?

Comment: wouldn't this be better suited for physics.stackexchange ?